# An Adjective for a Fast Reader

Tags: adjectives

So in The Chosen by Potok. One of the characters named Danny Saunders is a super fast reader. I have to write a Character Analysis report and turn it in before next Tuesday (16 Dec.). I was wondering what is a one-word ADJECTIVE that describes a fast reader? You see for this assignment you have to choose either one characteristic (adjective) for three people or three characteristics for one person.

Comment: If this helps, I have heard of "skimmer" (n)-a rapid but superficial reader.

Comment: You have compound words like "dynamic reader", "speed reading", but not a one-word adjective specific for "fast reader".

Comment: "Fast" *is* a one-word adjective that describes a fast reader.

Answer (score 1):

A one-word adjective?  Specific for a fast reader?  Sorry, but there isn't any.

Answer (score 0):

Someone who reads **a lot** could be described as an avid, rapacious, or avaricious reader. As for someone who reads quickly? These adjectives may occasionally be heard to be used for this use case in common usage, but, strictly speaking, they do not accurately apply.

Answer (score 0):

**word-sweeping** If your teacher doesn't like it, tell them to stop assigning things that stifle creativity.